# How to achieve header and footer as required?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, book-design, author

I have more than 100 abstracts for our conference which are categorized as `invited`, `contributory` and `poster`. Currently, I have file with the following sample code:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,twoside,french, english]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{needspace}  
\usepackage{babel}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%---------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%----------------------------------------------------
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,dsfont,amssymb,csquotes}

\newenvironment{keywords}{\noindent\textbf{Keywords:}}{}
\newenvironment{classification}{\noindent\textbf{AMS subject classifications.}}{}
\date{}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\texttt{\small #1}}

\newcommand{\atitle}[1]{\needspace{5cm} \begin{center}\bfseries\Large #1    \end{center}}
\newcommand{\aauthor}[1]{\begin{center}\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{\centering\small  #1} \end{center}}
\newcommand{\aaffil}[1]{\begin{center}\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{   \centering\small  #1}\end{center}   }

\newenvironment{abstract}{\begin{center}
\bfseries Abstract
\end{center} }{}


%%%%%--------For Bibliography----------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\subsection*}{}{}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}%
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%------------------------------------------------------- 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Abstracts: Invited Speakers}
%%First abstract------
\atitle{Title of the First abstract}
\aauthor{Author A$^1$ and Author B$^2$}
\aaffil{$^1$Institution of Author A\\ $^2$ Institution of Author B}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
 \begin{thebibliography}{100}
    \bibitem{[1]}   B. D. Sleeman. Multiparameter spectral theory and separation of variables. Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical. 41(1):1--20, 2008.
    \bibitem{[2]}   F. V. Atkinson. Multiparameter Spectral Theory, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 74: 1—27, 1968.
    \bibitem{[3]}   F. V. Atkinson. Multiparameter Eigenvalue Problems, Vol. I, (Matrices and Compact Operators) 1972: Academic Press, New York.
\end{thebibliography}

%%First abstract------
\atitle{Title of the Second abstract}
\aauthor{Author 2A$^1$ and Author 2B$^2$}
\aaffil{$^1$Institution of Author 2A\\ $^2$ Institution of Author 2B}
\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}
\begin{thebibliography}{100}
    \bibitem{[1]}   B. D. Sleeman. Multiparameter spectral theory and separation of variables. Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical. 41(1):1--20, 2008.
    \bibitem{[2]}   F. V. Atkinson. Multiparameter Spectral Theory, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 74: 1—27, 1968.
    \bibitem{[3]}   F. V. Atkinson. Multiparameter Eigenvalue Problems, Vol. I, (Matrices and Compact Operators) 1972: Academic Press, New York.
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

The output is the following:

[image]

I need the following changes in the header:

1. Section title should be there in the header like `\fancyhead[LE,LO]{section title}` and `\fancyhead[RE,RO]{Authors name without super scripts(ie, $^1$}`
2. Title of the article should be added in the content as `subsection` and the authors has to be added in the `subsubsection`.

How to achieve this?

Hope I can achieve the solution with the above setup with modifications.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following provides you with headers from the title and authors.  It does not strip the superscripts.  I honestly think you would be better off providing optional arguments to the `\atitle` and `\aauthor` commands to provide the text for the running heads as in general that material is going to be too long any way.

For the headers I have used `\markboth` in `\atitle` and `\extramarks` (from the `extramarks` package) in `\aauthor`.  This enables us to print authors that correspond to the given title, rather than these being chose from different abstracts.  Finally you have to stop the reference lists changing the marks by (further) patching `\thebibliography`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,french,english]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{babel}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%---------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr,extramarks}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\nouppercase \lastxmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%----------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,dsfont,amssymb,csquotes}

\newenvironment{keywords}{\noindent\textbf{Keywords:}}{}
\newenvironment{classification}{\noindent\textbf{AMS subject classifications.}}{}
\date{}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\texttt{\small #1}}

\newcommand{\atitle}[1]{\needspace{5cm} \begin{center}\bfseries\Large
  #1 \end{center}\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\aauthor}[1]{\begin{center}\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{\centering\small
  #1} \end{center}\extramarks{#1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\aaffil}[1]{\begin{center}\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{
  \centering\small #1}\end{center} }

\newenvironment{abstract}{\begin{center}
\bfseries Abstract
\end{center}}{}


%%%%%--------For Bibliography----------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\subsection*}{}{}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}%
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%-------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Abstracts: Invited Speakers}
%%First abstract------
\atitle{Title of the First abstract}
\aauthor{Author A$^1$ and Author B$^2$}
\aaffil{$^1$Institution of Author A\\ $^2$ Institution of Author B}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
 \begin{thebibliography}{100}
    \bibitem{[1]}   B. D. Sleeman. Multiparameter spectral theory and separation of variables. Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical. 41(1):1--20, 2008.
    \bibitem{[2]}   F. V. Atkinson. Multiparameter Spectral Theory, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 74: 1—27, 1968.
    \bibitem{[3]}   F. V. Atkinson. Multiparameter Eigenvalue Problems, Vol. I, (Matrices and Compact Operators) 1972: Academic Press, New York.
\end{thebibliography}

%%First abstract------
\atitle{Title of the Second abstract}
\aauthor{Author 2A$^1$ and Author 2B$^2$}
\aaffil{$^1$Institution of Author 2A\\ $^2$ Institution of Author 2B}
\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}
\begin{thebibliography}{100}
    \bibitem{[1]}   B. D. Sleeman. Multiparameter spectral theory and separation of variables. Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical. 41(1):1--20, 2008.
    \bibitem{[2]}   F. V. Atkinson. Multiparameter Spectral Theory, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 74: 1—27, 1968.
    \bibitem{[3]}   F. V. Atkinson. Multiparameter Eigenvalue Problems, Vol. I, (Matrices and Compact Operators) 1972: Academic Press, New York.
\end{thebibliography}
\atitle{Title of the third abstract}
\aauthor{Author 3A$^1$ and Author 3B$^2$}
\aaffil{$^1$Institution of Author 3A\\ $^2$ Institution of Author 3B}
\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}
\begin{thebibliography}{100}
    \bibitem{[1]}   B. D. Sleeman. Multiparameter spectral theory and separation of variables. Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical. 41(1):1--20, 2008.
    \bibitem{[2]}   F. V. Atkinson. Multiparameter Spectral Theory, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 74: 1—27, 1968.
    \bibitem{[3]}   F. V. Atkinson. Multiparameter Eigenvalue Problems, Vol. I, (Matrices and Compact Operators) 1972: Academic Press, New York.
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```